# Leaflet.js: How to remove multiple layers from map

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, maps, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js for a map. Now I want to remove added layers from the map. By clicking the input #button all checked checkboxes shall be changed to unchecked and all corresponding layers shall be removed from the map.

To remove a layer from the map the id of the layer is needed. This id equals the id of the corresponding checkbox. That's why I use jQuery to get the ids of all checked checkboxes and store their value in an object, here called *someObj.idsChecked*.

When I try to use the stored value *val* to remove one layer it doesn't work while the *console.log* displays the wanted value. Here for example: mapcat52.

While inserting the previous id hard coded into the function like *map.removeLayer(mapcat52)* it works as expected.

Where is the error in my code or my thoughts? 
 Any help is much appreciated.

The HTML

```
<input type="button" id="selectnone" value="deselect all" />

<!-- checkboxes  --> 
<input id="mapcat52" type="checkbox" name="maplayer" class="maplayer"> 
<label for="mapcat52">Map Layer One</label>

<input id="mapcat53" type="checkbox" name="maplayer" class="maplayer"> 
<label for="mapcat53">Map Layer Two</label>

...
```

The JS:

```
$('#selectnone').click(function() {
    var someObj = {};
    someObj.idsChecked = [];

    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            someObj.idsChecked.push($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    }).attr('checked', false);

    $.each(someObj.idsChecked,function(id, val) {

          // displays the wanted value, e.g. "mapcat52" if checkbox with this id is checked
          console.log(val);

          // does not work: inserted value
          map.removeLayer(val); 

          // works: hard coded value of the leaflet.js/input id
          map.removeLayer(mapcat52); 
        });

});
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186001/how-to-close-all-popups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Leaflet API doc http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer, removeLayer takes an ILayer parameter: `removeLayer( <ILayer> layer )` but you're passing it a String: `$(this).attr("id")`

It looks like you do have the layer object in a variable already: mapcat52.  You could save the layer objects when you create them, then look them up by id to pass to removeLayer:

```
var layers = new Array();

// create layer
var mapcat52 = new MyCustomLayer(latlng);

// save to layers list
layers["mapcat52"] = mapcat52;
...

// remove layers
$.each(someObj.idsChecked, function(id, val) {
    // look up layer object by id
    var layerObj = layers[val];
    // remove layer
    map.removeLayer(layerObj); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. This seems to fit to my case. I'll try that very soon.

Answer (score 23):

I would say the easiest way to remove/add (toggle) layers from the map would be to use a **LayerGroup**.

Before adding individual layers to the map, add them to a LayerGroup instead and then add that LayerGroup to your map.

Then when you have to remove the layers, just call the clearLayers() function.

Check out the API for LayerGroup http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

Example

```
var map = L.map('leafletMap', {minZoom:11}).setView([37.8, -96], 11);
var assetLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
var marker1 = L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.');
var marker2 = L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.'),
assetLayerGroup.addLayer(marker1);
assetLayerGroup.addLayer(marker2);
```

When remove checkbox is checked

```
assetLayerGroup.clearLayers();
```

Comment: thank you for the clean, clear example. so hard to find one of those!

Comment: Huge thanks, I've been struggling for a couple of hours now.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the below example to show how to remove multiples geoJSON layer.

///adding geoJSON data

```
      var myGeoJSON = L.geoJSON(myData, {

        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.myTag = "myGeoJSON"
        }

    });
```

////// function to remove geoJSON layers

```
var removeMarkers = function() {
    map.eachLayer( function(layer) {

      if ( layer.myTag &&  layer.myTag === "myGeoJSON") {
        map.removeLayer(layer)
          }

        });

}
```

//// calling function

removeMarkers();